# How is it possible to enable CORS from server-side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, browser, cors, same-origin-policy

From my little experience in web API, same origin policy is a policy of browsers i.e, browser doesn't allow to make requests to other hosts rather than the origin.  I wonder how it is possible to enable CORS from server side(talking about ASP.net Web API)?

**This is how i enable CORS in webAPI**

```
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods ...
    }
}
```

If CORS is a browser thing, isn't it more logical to enable it from client side. Can anybody clear this out

Comment: It is not "more logical" anymore if an user access your website and can enable cors just via javascript him/herself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s an attempt at a short summary of how it works: The browser is where the same-origin policy and cross-origin restrictions are enforced. Specifically, browsers block frontend JavaScript code from being able to access responses from cross-origin requests—*unless* the servers the requests are made to send the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in responses.

In other words, the way for getting browsers to relax the same-origin policy is for servers to use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to indicate they’re opting in to cross-origin requests.

So, browsers are the place where any cross-origin restrictions are either being applied or relaxed.

One case that helps to illustrate how it works is a simple cross-origin `POST`. As long as a cross-origin `POST` doesn’t have any custom request headers that will trigger browsers to do a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), a browser will go ahead and make the request, even cross-origin. And the server that `POST` is sent to will go ahead and accept it and then send a response.

What happens then is where the cross-origin restrictions from browsers kick in—because if that `POST` request was sent from frontend JavaScript code using XHR or the Fetch API or an Ajax method from some JavaScript library, then unless the response includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, browsers won’t allow the frontend code to access the response (even though the server accepted the `POST` and it succeeded).

Anyway, I hope the above helps to clarify what enabling CORS support in servers actually means, and what effects it has, and that the actual policy enforcement is performed by browsers.

Of course all of the above just describes the simplest case, where there are no characteristics of the request that will trigger browsers to do a [CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

But still in that case, the policy enforcement is all performed by the browser—in fact even more so, in that, for example, browsers won’t allow a `POST` with custom headers to even be sent to a server to begin with unless the server explicitly indicates  (in its response to the preflight `OPTIONS`) that the server has opted in to receiving cross-origin requests which include that custom header.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Here is what i understood. The browser anyway contacts the server regardless CORS is enabled or not in the server. If its enabled the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will be sent to the browser and browser proceeds again. Right?

Comment: @NithinChandran Right. What you describe is the gist of it—the browser contacts the server regardless, and if the server has CORS support enabled, then what that means is, it will send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in its reply.

Comment: @NithinChandran  But note that the browser doesn’t always exactly “proceed again” if it sees that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. Instead in the simplest case, that header just determines if the browser exposes the response to your code. But yeah in the case that the request is one that’s caused the browser to do a preflight, then based on the response to that preflight—if it has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers with the right values—then yeah, the browser proceeds to do the actual request